# Does compiling Imagick with OpenMP enabled, in FreeBSD 13.2, cause sched_yield() issues? And if so, how can this be resolved?

Tags: openmp, imagick

We have been using OpenMP with Imagick for as long as I can remember (several years), but after our system was recently updated system to FreeBSD 13.2 (RELEASE-p9) we have started experiencing random instances of processes getting locked at 100% CPU usage with truss revealing that sched_yield(); is being infinitely called on the locked processes. The locked processes never finish, and the only solution is to manually kill them.

When googling this issue, I was only able to find two mentions of this, and both seemed to point to this being a potential issue with compiling Imagick with OpenMP enabled on FreeBSD 13.2.

Has anyone else experienced this? If this is the case, is there a solution in the works? Disabling threads isn't a workable solution for us, since doing this significantly increases the amount of time it takes to process each image (5x or more), and we process a fairly large number of images on a daily basis.

For reference: FreeBSD 13.2-RELEASE-p9, PHP 8.1.27 (cli), ImageMagick 7.1.1-26.

The couple of similar mentions that I've seen of this can be found here:

https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=274135

https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/issue-with-ule-scheduler.85307/

---

Here is an example debug log showing the process locking with sched_yield(), and then never releasing.

```
    (gdb) thread apply all bt

Thread 1 (LWP 101575 of process 33247):
#0  sched_yield () at sched_yield.S:4
#1  0x00000008456d0491 in __kmp_wait_4_ptr (spinner=0x84573151c <__kmp_initz_lock+28>, checker=1, pred=0x8456eab50 <__kmp_bakery_check(void*, unsigned int)>, obj=0x845731500 <__kmp_initz_lock>) at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_dispatch.cpp:2695
#2  0x00000008456e97c8 in __kmp_acquire_ticket_lock_timed_template (lck=0x0, gtid=<optimized out>) at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_lock.cpp:640
#3  __kmp_acquire_ticket_lock (lck=0x0, gtid=<optimized out>) at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_lock.cpp:645
#4  0x00000008456ef564 in __kmp_acquire_bootstrap_lock (lck=0x84573151c <__kmp_initz_lock+28>) at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_lock.h:524
#5  __kmp_get_global_thread_id_reg () at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_runtime.cpp:253
#6  0x00000008456af91e in __kmp_entry_thread () at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp.h:3401
#7  kmpc_malloc (size=35524908316) at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_alloc.cpp:1098
#8  0x000000084572a1b7 in __kmp_is_address_mapped (addr=0x847bad5c8) at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/z_Linux_util.cpp:2067
#9  0x00000008456f9925 in __kmp_register_library_startup () at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_runtime.cpp:6774
#10 0x00000008456ef5c4 in __kmp_do_serial_initialize () at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_runtime.cpp:6966
#11 0x00000008456ef578 in __kmp_get_global_thread_id_reg () at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_runtime.cpp:255
#12 0x00000008456da0b2 in __kmp_api_omp_init_lock (user_lock=0x84573151c <__kmp_initz_lock+28>) at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_ftn_entry.h:1083
#13 0x0000000845bb773c in MagickCoreGenesis () from /usr/local/lib/libMagickCore-7.so.10
#14 0x00000008451f4d8e in zm_startup_imagick () from /usr/local/lib/php/20230831-debug/imagick.so
#15 0x000000000083b010 in zend_startup_module_ex ()
#16 0x000000000083bb10 in ?? ()
#17 0x0000000000853131 in zend_hash_apply ()
#18 0x000000000083b90c in zend_startup_modules ()
#19 0x0000000000766b0f in php_module_startup ()
#20 0x00000000009f51e9 in ?? ()
#21 0x00000000009f37a4 in ?? ()
#22 0x0000000000423720 in _start ()
(gdb)
```

And here is a second process that locked at the same time (pid 33248 vs 33247):

```
(gdb) thread apply all bt

Thread 1 (LWP 100499 of process 33248):
#0  sched_yield () at sched_yield.S:4
#1  0x00000008495aa491 in __kmp_wait_4_ptr (spinner=0x84960b51c <__kmp_initz_lock+28>, checker=1, pred=0x8495c4b50 <__kmp_bakery_check(void*, unsigned int)>, obj=0x84960b500 <__kmp_initz_lock>) at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_dispatch.cpp:2695
#2  0x00000008495c37c8 in __kmp_acquire_ticket_lock_timed_template (lck=0x0, gtid=<optimized out>) at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_lock.cpp:640
#3  __kmp_acquire_ticket_lock (lck=0x0, gtid=<optimized out>) at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_lock.cpp:645
#4  0x00000008495c9564 in __kmp_acquire_bootstrap_lock (lck=0x84960b51c <__kmp_initz_lock+28>) at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_lock.h:524
#5  __kmp_get_global_thread_id_reg () at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_runtime.cpp:253
#6  0x000000084958991e in __kmp_entry_thread () at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp.h:3401
#7  kmpc_malloc (size=35590812956) at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_alloc.cpp:1098
#8  0x00000008496041b7 in __kmp_is_address_mapped (addr=0x847bad5c8) at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/z_Linux_util.cpp:2067
#9  0x00000008495d3925 in __kmp_register_library_startup () at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_runtime.cpp:6774
#10 0x00000008495c95c4 in __kmp_do_serial_initialize () at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_runtime.cpp:6966
#11 0x00000008495c9578 in __kmp_get_global_thread_id_reg () at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_runtime.cpp:255
#12 0x00000008495b40b2 in __kmp_api_omp_init_lock (user_lock=0x84960b51c <__kmp_initz_lock+28>) at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_ftn_entry.h:1083
#13 0x000000084b24773c in MagickCoreGenesis () from /usr/local/lib/libMagickCore-7.so.10
#14 0x000000084a26bd8e in zm_startup_imagick () from /usr/local/lib/php/20230831-debug/imagick.so
#15 0x000000000083b010 in zend_startup_module_ex ()
#16 0x000000000083bb10 in ?? ()
#17 0x0000000000853131 in zend_hash_apply ()
#18 0x000000000083b90c in zend_startup_modules ()
#19 0x0000000000766b0f in php_module_startup ()
#20 0x00000000009f51e9 in ?? ()
#21 0x00000000009f37a4 in ?? ()
#22 0x0000000000423720 in _start ()
(gdb)
```

---

We have also tried updating to PHP 8.3.4, and the problem still remains.

---

Update: I have taken Imagick out of the equation and have recreated the same bug with just ImageMagick using the command-line `convert` operation. To recreate the bug outside of PHP,  I created two processes, with each process repeatedly adding a watermark to another image, and then I just waited for something to lock up.

I am adding watermarks to the top-left corner of another image using the following:
convert 'originalfile.jpg' 'watermarkfile.png' -set colorspace sRGB -gravity NorthWest -geometry +3+3 -define compose:args=20,100 -compose dissolve -composite 'resultingfile.jpg'

The trace information for the resulting locked processes from just using `convert` are as follows:

```
(gdb) thread apply all bt

Thread 1 (LWP 101740 of process 79048):
#0  sched_yield () at sched_yield.S:4
#1  0x0000000824f60491 in __kmp_wait_4_ptr (spinner=0x824fc151c <__kmp_initz_lock+28>, checker=1, pred=0x824f7ab50 <__kmp_bakery_check(void*, unsigned int)>, obj=0x824fc1500 <__kmp_initz_lock>) at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_dispatch.cpp:2695
#2  0x0000000824f797c8 in __kmp_acquire_ticket_lock_timed_template (lck=0x0, gtid=<optimized out>) at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_lock.cpp:640
#3  __kmp_acquire_ticket_lock (lck=0x0, gtid=<optimized out>) at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_lock.cpp:645
#4  0x0000000824f7f564 in __kmp_acquire_bootstrap_lock (lck=0x824fc151c <__kmp_initz_lock+28>) at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_lock.h:524
#5  __kmp_get_global_thread_id_reg () at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_runtime.cpp:253
#6  0x0000000824f3f91e in __kmp_entry_thread () at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp.h:3401
#7  kmpc_malloc (size=34980238620) at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_alloc.cpp:1098
#8  0x0000000824fba1b7 in __kmp_is_address_mapped (addr=0x8242955c8) at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/z_Linux_util.cpp:2067
#9  0x0000000824f89925 in __kmp_register_library_startup () at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_runtime.cpp:6774
#10 0x0000000824f7f5c4 in __kmp_do_serial_initialize () at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_runtime.cpp:6966
#11 0x0000000824f7f578 in __kmp_get_global_thread_id_reg () at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_runtime.cpp:255
#12 0x0000000824f6a0b2 in __kmp_api_omp_init_lock (user_lock=0x824fc151c <__kmp_initz_lock+28>) at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_ftn_entry.h:1083
#13 0x0000000821df77ac in MagickCoreGenesis () from /usr/local/lib/libMagickCore-7.so.10
#14 0x0000000000202512 in ?? ()
#15 0x00000000002022f0 in ?? ()
#16 0x00000000002021f0 in ?? ()
#17 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

And

```
(gdb) thread apply all bt

Thread 1 (LWP 153345 of process 79049):
#0  sched_yield () at sched_yield.S:4
#1  0x0000000825da5491 in __kmp_wait_4_ptr (spinner=0x825e0651c <__kmp_initz_lock+28>, checker=1, pred=0x825dbfb50 <__kmp_bakery_check(void*, unsigned int)>, obj=0x825e06500 <__kmp_initz_lock>) at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_dispatch.cpp:2695
#2  0x0000000825dbe7c8 in __kmp_acquire_ticket_lock_timed_template (lck=0x0, gtid=<optimized out>) at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_lock.cpp:640
#3  __kmp_acquire_ticket_lock (lck=0x0, gtid=<optimized out>) at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_lock.cpp:645
#4  0x0000000825dc4564 in __kmp_acquire_bootstrap_lock (lck=0x825e0651c <__kmp_initz_lock+28>) at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_lock.h:524
#5  __kmp_get_global_thread_id_reg () at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_runtime.cpp:253
#6  0x0000000825d8491e in __kmp_entry_thread () at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp.h:3401
#7  kmpc_malloc (size=34995201308) at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_alloc.cpp:1098
#8  0x0000000825dff1b7 in __kmp_is_address_mapped (addr=0x8246965c8) at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/z_Linux_util.cpp:2067
#9  0x0000000825dce925 in __kmp_register_library_startup () at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_runtime.cpp:6774
#10 0x0000000825dc45c4 in __kmp_do_serial_initialize () at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_runtime.cpp:6966
#11 0x0000000825dc4578 in __kmp_get_global_thread_id_reg () at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_runtime.cpp:255
#12 0x0000000825daf0b2 in __kmp_api_omp_init_lock (user_lock=0x825e0651c <__kmp_initz_lock+28>) at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_ftn_entry.h:1083
#13 0x00000008226c37ac in MagickCoreGenesis () from /usr/local/lib/libMagickCore-7.so.10
#14 0x0000000000202512 in ?? ()
#15 0x00000000002022f0 in ?? ()
#16 0x00000000002021f0 in ?? ()
#17 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Comment: The compiler you are using is also certainly relevant. Not that I have an answer, but the answer may well be different depending on the compiler, since this `sched_yield` call is clearly inside the OpenMP runtime. *If* you are using GCC, then you could try using the LLVM OpenMP runtime (libomp.so) instead of GCC's one (libgomp.so). I have no evidence that this will work, but changing the critical code might :-). Of course if it's a kernel issue, then this won't change anything.

Comment: Also, if possible, can you provide stacktraces for the threads? Attach gdb to the stale process. Then execute `thread apply all bt` in the gdb shell.

Comment: @Joachim I have added the debug details for one of the locked processes.

Comment: A deadlock usually is caused by a cyclic dependency of multiple executors (unless a thread tries to get a non-nested lock twice). Your backtrace shows the situation for the main thread. What is the state of other blocking threads?
Based on the backtrace, the OpenMP execution should be single-threaded (outside any parallel region) at this point. The OpenMP runtime tries to execute it's initialization code triggered by an omp_init_lock call from libMagick. Where are the other threads coming from? A bracktrace from another thread might provide some hints regarding this question.

Comment: Also, how many threads are there? How many threads are in `sched_yield` coming from `__kmp_acquire_ticket_lock_timed_template` and are there threads in `sched_yield` coming from a different lock function?

Comment: @Joachim I have added the trace information for the second process that locked at the same time (pid 33248 vs 33247). No additional processes were locked at the same time besides these two. In this case, both processes are PHP scripts that are executed as cron jobs scheduled to run every minute, and both got locked as they initialized before any actions happened within the scripts. As for your question about the number of sched_yield threads, I am not sure how to get that information.

Comment: @Joachim I have added additional trace data for another set of processes locked by ImageMagic. The difference with the new set of traces is that the processes were locked by the command-line `convert` command rather than by Imagick within PHP.

Answer (score 2):

This really is an issue in the LLVM OpenMP runtime (I created an issue for this: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/86684).

I'm not sure why you didn't see this issue before. It might be the case that FreeBSD moved from gcc compiled ImageMagick to clang compiled ImageMagick.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to mitigate the issue until it is fixed.